# Springboot JPA Same foreign key in Three different similar tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 tables. One table is mapped to 3 similar tables. The first table has a composite primary key which I want to map to three tables as a foreign key. All the fields are the same in the three child tables.

```
class Company{
    @Id
    private String companyId;
    @Id
    private String stateId;
    private String company Name;
}

class Managers{
    @Id
    private String id;
    //foreign key
    private String companyId;
    //foreign key
    private String stateId;
    private Int salary;
}

class SupportStaff{
    @Id
    private String id;
    //foreign key
    private String companyId;
    //foreign key
    private String stateId;
    private Int salary;
}
```

The data is huge since I am retrieving the value one at a time and on different rules. I have to keep them separate. Is it possible to map it and get it based on rest? If I want a list of managers, I want to retrieve from the managers table and from SupportStaff table if I want support staff details.

Comment: Please confirm my understanding is correct or not, if you create three separate model for this implementation then call based model only need to call like if call SupportStaff that only model you need right?

Comment: If it’s your requirement means use fetchtype LAZY in your model creation it’s only fetch the data at getter method call

Comment: At a time , I will fetch the records only from 1 child table

Comment: Then you use JoinColumn with fetchType Lazy

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood you should add mapping annotations as per your use case

`@OneToMany` / `@ManyToMany` / and others to the columns you want as foreign keys

while fetching, you will need JOIN queries to fetch the data

refer to [JPA join column](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column) 
and [JPQL inner join](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-inner-join.html).

Comment: I have composite primary key in my primary tables. I want the same as foreign key in my three child tables where relation is oneToMany. How can I map composite primary key with foreign key in three tables